# Persistence unit missing dependencies migrating from JBoss EAP 6.4 to 7.0

Tags: jboss, jboss-eap-7

I have an application that must run on both JBoss EAP 6.4 and 7.0. The application uses EJB entity beans which are no longer supported on JBoss EAP 7 so the entity beans are being migrated to use JPA entities as described in the JBoss migration guide. The application deploys and works fine on 6.4 but fails to deploy with "missing dependencies" error on 7.0. I've seen alot of issues where the missing dependency was the datasource but that doesn't seem to be the case here. The datasource isn't mentioned at all in the missing dependencies error. I can see in the logs the persistence.xml file is being parsed and the jndi bindings added for the session beans before the deployment fails.

I have an EAR file that contains multiple war and ejb jar files. The application I'm having an issue with consists of an ejbModule.jar which contains the persistence.xml file and entity classes, and a webModule.war file with taglib classes that reference the entity classes contained in ejbModule.jar.

The structure of the EAR file is outlined below:

MyEAR.ear
 - ejbJar.jar
 - webApp1.war
 - webApp2.war
 - ejbModule.jar (contains persistence.xml and entity classes)
 -- META-INF/persistence.xml
 - webModule.jar (taglib classes have dependency on entity classes from ejbModule.jar)
 - META-INF

persistence.xml: (replaced class names, datasource name, persistence-unit name)

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns:per="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="myPU">
    <class>org.MyEntity1</class>
    <class>org.MyEntity2</class>
    <jta-data-source>java:/MyDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:/myPU"/>
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/myPU"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

It's difficult to post the error message as it's got hundreds of lines of "missing dependencies" for class names and application names that I can't share and by the time I replace them all I don't feel it would be of much use. But there are entries like:

*"jboss.naming.context.java.comp.MyEAR.ejbModule.MyEntity1.InAppClientContainer is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.comp.MyEAR.ejbModule.MyEntity1]",*

However there also entries like:

*"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"MyEAR.ear\".\"webApp1.war\".component.\"org.taglib.MyTagLibClass\".START is missing [jboss.persistenceunit.\"MyEAT.ear/ejbModule.jar#myPU\"]"*

I can see from the DEBUG logging for org.jboss.as.jpa that JBoss looks to be adding dependencies on the persistence unit for all taglib classes in all war files in the ear. Only the webModule.war needs to use the persistence unit.

*2017-12-07 15:37:13,808 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-2) Adding dependency on PU service service jboss.persistenceunit."MyEAR.ear#myPU" for component org.taglib.MyTagLibClass*

When I move the persistence.xml file to the META-INF directory of the EAR the application deploys and works fine on JBoss EAP 7.0. However, this isn't an ideal solution as the EAR file is built dynamically and could contain custom applications that I have no control over. 
I've tried various other structures to try and get this working but haven't found anything else that works.

Any ideas how to get this working on JBoss EAP 7.0?

Answer (score 0):

There are unnecessary entries in your persistence.xml

You just need this

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns:per="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="myPU">
    <jta-data-source>java:/MyDataSource</jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
```

Because the entities will be found automatically relative to persistence.xml

Please try this and if doesn't help please post as much of the server.log as you can.

Another idea could be to ask the RedHat support as you use EAP I assume that you have subscriptions containing support.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the app still doesn't deploy. It fails with the same errors as described above.

Comment: Please provide the whole logfile. I can't help you with just and excerpt